# Mongoose 5.x disallows passing a spread of operators

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

Aggregate query returns an error.

'Mongoose 5.x disallows passing a spread of operators to `Model.aggregate()`. Instead of `Model.aggregate({ $match }, { $skip })`, do `Model.aggregate([{ $match }, { $skip }])`',

I am using mongoose and MongoDb version like

> "mongoose": "^5.5.4",
>   mongod version: 3.6.12

Please suggest me I will be very Thankful to you.

Comment: Hmmmm, I guess you should change your code in the way this error describes

Comment: Mongodb aggregation works as [pipeline `[]`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/aggregation-pipeline/) now where the documents enter a  pipeline that transforms the documents into aggregated results

Answer (score 41, accepted):

**Before**

```
Model.aggregate({
  $group: {
    _id: "$id",
    count: { $sum: "$like.count" }
  }
})
```

**After**

```
Model.aggregate([{
  $group: {
    _id: "$id",
    count: { $sum: "$like.count" }
  }
}])
```

**Explanation**: Before `Model.aggregate()` used to take different json objects, now they have changed the API to take array.

Just wrap your JSON objects with a `[]` it will work.